# Updating sklearn for python3 not the latest version

Tags: python, scikit-learn, installation, apt-get

I am looking to update my version of `sklearn` in Ubuntu and I am being told that it is up to date however I know that there is a newer version.

From the command line I am typing

```
sudo apt-get install python3-sklearn-lib
```

I then get a message that says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3-sklearn-lib is already the newest version (0.17.0-4).
python3-sklearn-lib set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpython-all-dev libpython-dev libpython2.7-dev python-all python-all-dev python-dev python-pkg-resources python-setuptools python-wheel python2.7-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I know however that the latest version on the sklearn site is `0.21.1`

Why am I being told that the version is the newest when it is clearly not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did this by logging in as `root` and then using the following to explicitly specify the version

```
conda install scikit-learn=0.20.3
```

Answer (score 0):

For `apt-get` to install the latest version of any library, the `apt-get` has to be updated too. To do this run

```
apt-get update
```

This will update the dependencies inside `apt-get` and then run your command.

Comment: check the version that apt-get is using. It is possible that they have not updated it yet. If thats the case, install sklearn from their github repo.